# Selected value in select multiple box

Tags: php, html

```
    $excludeship = unserialize($data[0]['exclush']); //from database

    $excludecountry = ""; //data from API

$excludehtml =  <select multiple id="excludeship" name="excludeship" class="form-control excludeship">

  foreach ($excludeship as $key4 => $value4){    //from database
        foreach ($excludecountry as $key => $value){    //data from API             
            $excludehtml .= '<optgroup label='.$key.'>';
                    foreach ($value as $v){
                        if($v['value'] == $value4){                             
$excludehtml .=     '<option value='.$v['value']. selected>'.$v['Description'].'</option>';
                                }else{
                                     $excludehtml .= '<option value='.$v['value'].'>'.$v['Description'].'</option>';
                                }
                            }
                            $excludehtml .= '</optgroup>';                  
                        }
                    }
$excludehtml .=   </select>
```

[result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx1mh.png)

**Question:** Above code is that to display the select box in front end, the code that I wrote that will be the error which is duplicate the option value, but is fine to selected the value. May I know how to do that which selected the value and the option data won't duplicate?

Comment: sorry but its a bit unclear what you're asking, possibly either 1) rename `name="excludeship"` to `name="excludeship[]"` if you do want multiple selections or 2) remove `multiple` if you don't want multiple selections.

Comment: `$excludehtml =  <select... excludeship">` that is an outright parse error. Same for `$excludehtml .=   </select>`. Why don't you post the real code, or is that your real code?